# variable named TYPE_BOOL(c++ code) is conflicted with ios macro

Tags: c++, ios, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build protobuf c++ into ios.
But its implementation contains a TYPE_BOOL enum variable that conflicts with TYPE_BOOL in ios macro. And compile failed.

How to solve this?

Comment: Dont include that file from Obj-C, and wrap it around http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/316738-nil-and-nil-macro-conflict.html

Answer (score 2):

There are a few reasonable (but hacky) options:

1. `#include` any protobuf headers that use `TYPE_BOOL` *before* you `#include` any iOS headers.  Example:

   ```
   #include <google/protobuf/descriptor.h>
   #include <ConditionalMacros.h>
   ```

   This lets you use iOS's `TYPE_BOOL` in your own code, but not protobuf's `TYPE_BOOL`.
2. `#include` the iOS header, then `#undef TYPE_BOOL` before you `#include` the protobuf header.  Example:

   ```
   #include <ConditionalMacros.h>
   #undef TYPE_BOOL
   #include <google/protobuf/descriptor.h>
   ```

   This lets you use protobuf's `TYPE_BOOL` in your own code, but not iOS's `TYPE_BOOL`.
3. If you need both definitions, this might work (not tested):

   ```
   #include <google/protobuf/descriptor.h>

   // Make a copy of TYPE_BOOL before it is hidden by a macro.
   const google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor::Type PROTOBUF_TYPE_BOOL =
       google::protobuf::FieldDescriptor::TYPE_BOOL;

   #include <ConditionalMacros.h>
   ```

   Now use `PROTOBUF_TYPE_BOOL` when you need the Protobuf definitions.

Note that `google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h` also defines a `TYPE_BOOL`.  It can be solved in the same way, but most people don't use that header, so I left it out of the examples.